# How to edit dataframe to correct values, preferably without a loop?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

currently, I have a dataframe that looks like this

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 3G |
| 02 | 94 |
| 03 | 78 |
| 04 | 3L |

The Heading 2 values are wrong and suppose to be 113G, 0994, 0978, and 113N.

My attempt at this looks like

```
Correct_List = [113G, 0994, 0978, 113N]
Incorrect_List = [94, 3G, 3L, 78]
    
def correcting(df, list_1, list_2):
    
   for (two_digit, four_digit) in zip(list_1, list_2) :
      if two_digit == four_digit[-2:]:
           df['DDIST'] = np.where((df.DDIST == two_digit), four_digit, df.DDIST)
   return df
```

I ran the function and checked the data frame, but nothing happened.

The desired output is:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 113G |
| 02 | 0994 |
| 03 | 0978 |
| 04 | 113L |

Also, any method better than the loop would also be appreciated, since the actual data frame and loop are very big

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of key, value pairs from your incorrect and correct lists, then call `replace` passing the dictionary for the column.

```py
>>> mapping={k:v for k,v in zip(Incorrect_List, Correct_List)}
>>> df['Heading 2']=df['Heading 2'].replace(mapping)
df
  Heading 1 Heading 2
0        01      0994
1        02      113G
2        03      113N
3        04      0978
```

Answer (score 0):

in the provided sample, the last value should be 3N, instead of 3L.

create a dictionary from the correct values, taking last two as key and then mapping in the DF

```
d= {i[2:]:i for i in Correct_List}
df['Heading 2']=df['Heading 2'].map(d)
df
```

```
    Heading 1   Heading 2
0           1     113G
1           2     0994
2           3     0978
3           4     113N
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the correct values in a list? If yes, you could just reassign all the values in the DF column like this:

```
df['Heading 2'] = Correct_List
```

But if you need some custom logic, rather than looping through the data frame, convert the column into a list, apply your logic and then reassign the values in the DF.

```
x = df['Heading 2'].tolist()
# perform whatever logic you need
df['Heading 2'] = x
```